# discord.py - how do you add components to discord bot messages, currently?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

A lot of the guides and questions are out of date - all the ones I found, in fact. They recommend third-party libraries, or don't show any python code, just component information. The one guide I found that included code was in JS.

What I want is for any user to be able to click on a button in a message that runs the same command over again. In order, that's

```
user1: /d20 5 2
bot: @user1 got [2,22,3,17,5]/20; [repeat]
user2: *clicks repeat*
bot: @user2 got [9,7,14,2,18]/20; [repeat]
```

Ideally it would bring up a modal window with the parameters in case they want to tweak them, but that's a question for another day. All the code is written for the interaction except for the `[repeat]` button components, it even replies to the right message. I can probably write the formatting for an action row with a single button, that part doesn't look too hard or too varied across tutorials.

I'm essentially copying the behavior I've seen in Midjourney outputs; depending on whether you have remix mode on or off, you get either immediate response or a modal window, and the modal window has an immediate response. But because there's no message to reply to with the right author, I don't expect it to be a reply, just a message that @references the person who clicked the button.

Comment: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/counter.py